# Rails_admin, Adding model that embeds itself causes infinite loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, rails-admin

I have created Mongoid model:

```
class Profile
   include Mongoid::Document
   include Mongoid::Timestamps

   embeds_many :sub_profiles, class_name: 'Profile', cyclic: true, inverse_of: :profile

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :sub_profiles

end
```

When I open page where I can create or edit `Profile` my application just hangs. When I opened logs, it shows me that It tries to **load html templates infinitely and just hangs.**

I just wanted to dynamically add new `:sub_profiles` inside profile. What do I need to do?

When I try to access to my `sub_profiles` via rails console it works fine.